# PL/SQL identifier 'string' must be declared

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, plsqldeveloper

Can anyone tell me why this won't execute?

```
set serveroutput on ;
Declare
   TYPE type_emp IS RECORD(
        emp_name employees.last_name%TYPE,
        emp_salary employees.salary%TYPE);
     rec_emp type_emp;
   due_for_a_raise CHAR(1);
begin
   SELECT last_name, salary into rec_emp
   from employees
   where employee_id = 150;
   if emp_salary > 5000 then
      due_for_a_raise := 'Y';
     else
      due_for_a_raise := 'N';
   end if;
  dbms_output.putline(last_name);
  dbms_output.putline(salary);
  dbms_output.putline(due_for_a_raise);
end;
```

Errors are below

```
Error report:
ORA-06550: line 11, column 6:
PLS-00201: identifier 'EMP_SALARY' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 11, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 16, column 23:
PLS-00201: identifier 'LAST_NAME' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 16, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 17, column 23:
PLS-00201: identifier 'SALARY' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 17, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 18, column 15:
PLS-00302: component 'PUTLINE' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 18, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

I guess I don't know why it isn't being declared since they are being declared in the type_emp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd need to use the record when you're referencing them.  Your calls to `dbms_output.put_line` also need to have an underscore between `put` and `line`.

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  Declare
  2     TYPE type_emp IS RECORD(
  3          emp_name employees.last_name%TYPE,
  4          emp_salary employees.salary%TYPE);
  5       rec_emp type_emp;
  6     due_for_a_raise CHAR(1);
  7  begin
  8     SELECT last_name, salary
  9       into rec_emp
 10       from employees
 11      where employee_id = 150;
 12     if rec_emp.emp_salary > 5000 then
 13        due_for_a_raise := 'Y';
 14       else
 15        due_for_a_raise := 'N';
 16     end if;
 17    dbms_output.put_line(rec_emp.emp_name);
 18    dbms_output.put_line(rec_emp.emp_salary);
 19    dbms_output.put_line(due_for_a_raise);
 20* end;
SQL> /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```